# Symfony twig service user from token storage is null sometimes

Tags: symfony

I have a service that I have defined as a global twig variable that makes use of autowiring the TokenStorageInterface in order to get the current logged in user.

*Sometimes* the token is null and throws an exception when trying to access a null object. `Call to a member function getUser() on null`

This is the barebone code that breaks.

BonusService.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Service;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class BonusService {

    private $user;
    private $manager;

    __construct(TokenStorageInterface, $tokenStorage, ObjectManager $manager) {
        $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();    // Sometimes fails here
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function hasBonuses() {
        return count($this->manager->getRepository(Bonus::class)->findBy(array('contact' => $user)) > 0;
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: true

    AppBundle\Service\BonusService:
```

config.yml

```
twig:
    ...
    globals:
        bonus_service: '@AppBundle\Service\BonusService'
```

index.html.twig

```
...
{% if bonus_service.hasBonuses %}Have Bonuses{% endif %}
...
```

I've been googling reasons as to why the token storage may be null when twig is doing it's thing. One issue predominately came appeared is to assure that my route is behind a firewall, which in this case it is and requires an authenticated user.

Also with noting is that I have a similar service with an identical constructor which is utilised within a controller. When the `BonusService` doesn't decide to use a null token and the page loads, the other service has no problem grabbing a token. When I remove the call to the service in twig, the page loads 100% of the time, even with the other service and it's identical constructor.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: When user is not logged in, it will give you null

Comment: @Eakethet in this case the user is logged in. (I usually have the token surrounded by an `is_null()` clause but for brevity I didn't include it in the snippet)

Comment: You should store the reference to the token storage and not get the user in the constructor. The token might still be null but the app is in two different states - when the constructor is called the container is still booting up .

Comment: Or you can avoid storing user in service and do something like bonus_service.hasBonuses, {user: app.user }

Comment: please, never, ever, change the code (apart for variable/password/etc shadowing) you post here. Removing `is_null` changes everything.

Comment: Thanks @vstm! I managed to get it to work by assigning the tokenStorage to a class property and creating a `getUser()` method to fetch the user when needed. Could you make your comment an answer so that I may accept it?

Comment: @Eakethet I thought about that however there may be some cases where I would like to reuse this service in other situations that may extend outside of twig. I would rather have it autowired into the service than have to come up with other messy ways to find the user in other contexts.

Comment: @SteppingHat eg. you wanna know, if someone else has bonuses, not the user that is actually logged in, so for me, it looks more reusable, when you pass User as param, but I dont know your bussines case

Comment: @Eakethet ah yeah I see what you mean. But yeah in this case it will always be for the currently logged in user as there are supporting functions that are called specific to logged in users

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating services your constructor should avoid executing much beyond storing the injected services as a reference.

```
class BonusService {

    private $tokenStorage;
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, ObjectManager $manager) {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function hasBonuses() {
        if (!$this-tokenStorage->getToken() instanceof User) {
             return false;
        }
        return count($this->manager->getRepository(Bonus::class)->findBy(array(
            'contact' => $this-tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser())
        ) > 0;
    }
}
```

You still have to check if the token is set and is an instance of User (or however your User is called).

The reason you should  not use any of the injected services at in the constructor is because at that stage the container is still booting up and building all the services. So your dependencies might not yet be initialized fully.